# Save copy of log if an [Error] is ever detected

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

Is this a simple thing to do with the python logging library. Say I have a log output like so:

```
[2016-02-19 10:47:21,128] [    INFO] --- Setting up window... (Calipso.py:690)
[2016-02-19 10:47:21,128] [    INFO] --- Placed toolswindow at: 1x1+1642+373... (Calipso.py:184)
[2016-02-19 10:47:21,128] [    INFO] --- Setting up menu... (Calipso.py:692)
[2016-02-19 10:47:21,144] [    INFO] --- Setting up main screen... (Calipso.py:694)
[2016-02-19 10:47:21,144] [    INFO] --- Creating upper program GUI... (Calipso.py:192)
[2016-02-19 10:47:21,144] [    INFO] --- Setting up toolbar... (toolswindow.py:86)
[2016-02-19 10:47:21,144] [    INFO] --- Creating toolbar buttons... (toolswindow.py:154)
[2016-02-19 10:47:21,144] [    INFO] --- Setting initial plot... (Calipso.py:210)
[2016-02-19 10:47:21,144] [ WARNING] --- set_plot called for BASE_PLOT... (manager.py:249)
[2016-02-19 10:47:24,779] [    INFO] --- Importing HDF file... (Calipso.py:237)
[2016-02-19 10:47:30,861] [    INFO] --- Grabbing range and safe checking... (toolswindow.py:335)
[2016-02-19 10:47:30,861] [    INFO] --- Calling plot... (toolswindow.py:339)
[2016-02-19 10:47:30,861] [   ERROR] --- Needs to be reimplemented... (Calipso.py:370)
[2016-02-19 10:47:31,549] [   ERROR] --- IOError, no file exists... (Calipso.py:385)
```

Now obviously something bad happened, but if for some reason the program still worked (maybe the file is a backend file and the user wouldn't know if it was loaded or not), he may overwrite the log file the next time he run unknowingly erasing any logs of that error.

Is there a way to save a log as a different filename in the event that an `error` appears in it? Maybe some sort of python destructor I can create so that when the program is about to close, I can open the file and look for any errors or something?

P.S. if my actual logger configuration is relevant I can post that.

Comment: Why not add a specific handler setting the level to error? If you really want to back that up then tee the output to a second file or just use append so you don't lose data

Comment: Why not create a different log file for each user and session?

Comment: You could also use something like  Sentry or Rollbar which both actually has a free plan to email you on if there is any error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`MemoryHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#memoryhandler) to buffer records in memory and output them if an error (or greater) is seen:

> The MemoryHandler class, located in the logging.handlers module,
>   supports buffering of logging records in memory, periodically flushing
>   them to a target handler. Flushing occurs whenever the buffer is full,
>   or when an event of a certain severity or greater is seen.